# PHP - What is wrong with this?

Tags: php

Any idea what's wrong with this?

```
<h1>IP Logger</h1>
<?php
$file = 'ip/index.php';
$date = date('d/m/y');
$time = date('H:i:s');


if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$log = '<a href="'. $ip . '">'. $ip . ' </a><br>';
$infofileloc = 'ip/' . $ip . '/index.php';

$infofile = 'Nothing here yet!';

$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/' . $ip . '/json"));
$city = $details->city;
$hostname = $details->hostname;
$region = $details->region;
$country = $details->country;
$loc = $details->loc;
$org = $details->org;

$data = "<h1>". $ip . "</h1><br>Date: " . $date . "<br>Time: " . $time . "<br>Hostname: " . $hostname . "<br>City: " . $city . "<br>Country: " . $country . "<br>Region: " . $region . "<br>Location: " . $loc . "<br>ISP Org: " . $org . "<br>"

echo("Writing IP to log...<br>");
file_put_contents($file, $log);
echo("Done.<br>");
echo("Writing information file to log...<br>");
if (!file_exists('ip/' . $ip)) {
    mkdir('ip/'. $ip, 0777, true) or die("ERROR: Unable to create info directory in /ip/!<br>");
}

file_put_contents("ip/" . $ip . "/index.php", $data);
echo("Done.<br>");
echo($ip . "<br>");
?>
<br>
<a href="ip">Access Logs</a>
```

I just get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/u142114406/public_html/i/index.php on line 30
```

Any ideas? :S

I've no idea whats wrong here, I think it is something to do with the last file_put_contents but am unsure.

Thanks,
-Connor

Comment: I imagine you’ve missed a semi-colon on line 29, if it’s complaining about an unexpected `echo` on line 30.

Comment: At this line: `$data = ...` no semicolon

Comment: Sorry, I feel really stupid now. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a semicolon at the end of line #28:

```
$data = "<h1>". $ip . "</h1>"...
```

This kind of error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO..` usually notifies a certain line number, but when it happens you should always look at the line **PRIOR** to the one you are getting an error on.

Please now consider seeing the Help -> Tour otherwise you're going to be considered off topic.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think :S My appologies

Answer (score 0):

It has an `echo` where it isn't expecting one; you forgot the semi-colon at the end of the previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no semi-colon ";" end of line 28

28. Line with starting => $data = "". $ip . ...

Btw use this class : http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5680-PHP-Get-geographic-location-of-a-given-IP-address.html

or

http://community.sitepoint.com/t/simple-ip-logging-script/4042

Comment: I am using maxmind.com for ip related database information. It is Open Source.